# Understanding uname output

Tags: unix, uname

What do the various pieces of `uname -a` output mean? Following is an example output:

```
Linux mymachine 2.6.18-194.e15PAE #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 15:37:44 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I gather that Linux is the O.S, 2.6.18-194.e15PAE is the kernel version. What do the rest of the pieces mean?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: in a console, type `man uname` and all will become clear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order, the fields are:

- "Linux": The machine's kernel name (e.g, OS).
- "mymachine": The machine's node name (e.g, hostname).
- "2.6.18-194.e15PAE": The kernel version
- "#1 SMP Fri Apr 2 15:37:44 EDT 2010": The kernel version and build time.
- "i686 i686": The processor type and hardware platform.
- "i386": The architecture of the processor. (This and the two above basically all mean the same thing on most systems. They typically only differ on certain embedded platforms.)
- "GNU/Linux": The operating system name.

For comparison, the `uname -a` from my Mac reads:

- "Darwin" (hardware name)
- "mymachine"
- "Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0" (version)
- "Sat Jun 18 12:56:35 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64" (build time)
- "x86_64" (processor architecture)
- (The operating system name is omitted by the OS X version of uname for some reason, as are a few other fields.)

Comment: So, if I wanted to make sure that a server was up to date with patches, all I would have to do is look at that output and make sure the build was within the date range my admin policy specifies (last three months), right?

Comment: @AgapwIesu No. The build time in the output of `uname` only reflects the version of the kernel, not any other software on the system.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify, I am only concerned with making sure that the **OS** is up to date with patches to within 3 months of "today".  I don't need to care about other software at this point.  For that, is that kernel build date/time enough?... am I giving away that I am a Windows guy?... should this be a separate question?

Comment: @AgapwIesu Again: no. Having an up-to-date kernel does not mean that all (or even any) other software on the machine has been updated.

Comment: To be more precise: 
`i686 i686` is `machine hardware name` and `processor type`. 
`i386` is `hardware platform`.

Comment: Does kernel version "#1" can be different than 1?