# `numpy.random.normal` generates different numbers on different systems

Tags: python, linux, numpy, random, numpy-random

I'm comparing the numbers generated with [`np.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) on two different systems (details see below) with the following code (I'm using the legacy [`np.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) because this is used by another program whose output I want to verify eventually) <sup>(1)</sup> :

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.normal(scale=1e-3, size=10**5)
np.save('test.npy', x)
```

Then I copy the `test.npy` from one system to the other where I compare the two versions:

```py
>>> other = np.load('test.npy')
>>> (x != other).sum(), len(x)
(29, 100000)
>>> mask = x != other
>>> np.abs(x[mask] - other[mask])
array([5.42101086e-20, 1.35525272e-20, 2.71050543e-20, 5.42101086e-20,
       1.08420217e-19, 1.08420217e-19, 2.16840434e-19, 2.16840434e-19,
       1.35525272e-20, 1.08420217e-19, 1.08420217e-19, 5.42101086e-20,
       2.71050543e-20, 1.08420217e-19, 2.16840434e-19, 5.42101086e-20,
       2.71050543e-20, 2.16840434e-19, 2.16840434e-19, 2.71050543e-20,
       2.71050543e-20, 1.08420217e-19, 1.08420217e-19, 1.08420217e-19,
       5.42101086e-20, 1.08420217e-19, 1.08420217e-19, 5.42101086e-20,
       2.71050543e-20])
>>> x[mask]
array([ 4.52489093e-04,  9.78961454e-05, -1.47113076e-04, -3.67859222e-04,
       -5.33279620e-04,  8.40794952e-04, -7.75987295e-04,  1.34205479e-03,
        6.34459482e-05,  5.07109360e-04, -7.68363366e-04,  3.33350262e-04,
       -2.19367067e-04,  6.11402140e-04, -1.30486526e-03, -4.42699624e-04,
        1.45463287e-04, -1.22491651e-03,  1.05226781e-03, -2.43032730e-04,
       -2.40551279e-04,  4.95396595e-04, -7.25454745e-04, -8.50779215e-04,
       -2.66274662e-04,  7.28854386e-04,  8.38515107e-04,  3.36152654e-04,
       -1.26550328e-04])
```

So there are 29 out of 100,000 elements that differ by a tiny amount. However, I do not understand where this difference comes from. I verified that I have the same version of Python and NumPy installed on both systems: `python==3.9.4` and `numpy==1.20.2` (obtained via `python -m pip install numpy==1.20.2`; but I also checked with the latest version `numpy==1.23.0` and the results are exactly the same). I verified that the RNG state (via `np.random.get_state()`) is the same on both systems before and after the call to `np.random.normal`. I saved and copied the `test.npy` file multiple times and I also verified it via MD5 checksum, so the difference must originate in the random number generation itself <sup>(1)</sup>. However, I can't see how this is possible, given that both are initiated with the same random state.

### Information about systems

**System A** (the one where `test.npy` is saved):

```
$ uname -a
Linux SystemA 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 10 13:32:12 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(I also tested on another system A2 which has the same OS version installed as A but is equipped with different CPUs, but the results didn't change from A to A2, i.e. I suspect it's the OS version).

**System B** (the one where `test.npy` is loaded):

```
$ uname -a
Linux SystemB 5.4.0-113-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 14:30:56 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

**Footnote (1):** When I use the recommend way given in the docs of [`np.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html), i.e. `rs = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(0)))`, I find that the discrepancy between the two systems remains. However, when I use `np.random.default_rng(seed=0)` instead, i.e. the new [`PCG64`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/pcg64.html), I find that the discrepancy goes away.

Comment: In case anyone else is confused by the [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943803/understanding-uname-output) of `uname -a` as well.

Comment: Perhaps it is due to the properties of floating point numbers? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065437/floating-point-math-in-python-numpy-not-reproducible-across-machines

Comment: Related (not intended to answer this question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761837/in-r-how-can-i-get-prng-to-give-identical-floating-point-numbers-between-platfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the differences are all so small, it suggests that the underlying bit-generators are doing the same things.  It's just to do with differences between the underlying math library.

NumPy's [legacy generator](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b0b523ec0980e46ca735ce96c7c976c4fdd28424/numpy/random/src/legacy/legacy-distributions.c#L18) uses `sqrt` and `log` from `libm`, and you can see that it pulls in these symbols by first finding the shared object providing the generator via:

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.random.mtrand.__file__)
```

then dumping symbols with:

```bash
nm -C -gD mtrand.*.so | grep GLIBC
```

where that `mtrand` filename comes from the above output.

I get a lot of other symbols output, but that might explain the differences.

At a guess it's to do with the `log` implementation, so you could test with:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

x = 2 * np.random.rand(2, 10**5) - 1
r2 = np.sum(x * x, axis=0)

np.save('test-log.npy', np.log(r2))
```

and compare between these two systems.

Comment: This seems to be the reason, indeed. I compared `r2` (also made sure that `0 < r2 < 1` is satisfied) and the numbers agree between the two systems. Then I compare `np.log(r2)` and these do disagree. It's interesting that for the resulting normal values only such a small fraction is affected; is there a way to see the implementation of `libm` functions? And how can I find out the `libm` versions? I checked `ldconfig -p | grep libm\\.` and it gives me `libm.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32)` vs. `libm.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0)`; are those the library version numbers?

Comment: However, how would that explain that for `PCG64` there are no differences? Is it just "luck" for the `10**5` samples I created? I see that the new version of `random_normal` uses [`npy_log1p`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b0b523ec0980e46ca735ce96c7c976c4fdd28424/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L158) but that presumably uses `log` under the hood, too? Also, it uses [`exp`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b0b523ec0980e46ca735ce96c7c976c4fdd28424/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L166) which likely has different implementations, too (?).

Comment: That may be because `PCG64` is part of a new system in NumPy for pseudorandom generation, since version 1.17.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599149/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-randoms-generator-class-and-np-random-meth/60609480#60609480).  Also the differences in your question may be due to implementation differences in floating-point numbers; see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761837/in-r-how-can-i-get-prng-to-give-identical-floating-point-numbers-between-platfo) involving the R language.

Comment: @a_guest determining where code comes from is very system specific.  I'd suggest asking your distribution's package manager (e.g. under debian/ubuntu you'd use [dpkg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224186/90376)) and then search for the source code associated with that version of package.