# How to rollback the state of a random computation in python?

Tags: python-3.x, random, sample

Let's assume that I want to use the function `sample()` within the `random` module in python on input `[1,2,3,4]` and obtain `[2,3,1,4]`.

My objective is now rolling back this operation to obtain the previous state, meaning that I want to again apply the `sample()` (or any other function) on `[2,3,1,4]` so that the result is back to `[1,2,3,4]`.

This is kind of I need an `unsample()` instruction.

Can I do it by the use of `setstate()` and `getstate`??

Comment: *Can I do it by the use of setstate() and getstate??* Try it and see. Don't be afraid to experiment.

Comment: note that moving the state to another machine might cause some of the "real-valued" distributions to return sightly different values.  e.g. uniform will probably be OK, but normal/Gaussian distribution might not.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72817047/1358308 (which was noticed via Numpy, but I'd expect the same artifact via the `random` module)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get back to the original input of `[1,2,3,4]`, it's easy. Just don't clobber the original with your sample. Put the results of sampling into a different variable:

```python
import random

my_data = [1,2,3,4]
print(f"original before sampling: {my_data}")

sampled_data = random.sample(my_data, 4)
print(f"after sampling, original: {my_data}, sample: {sampled_data}")
```

produces, for example:

```text
original before sampling: [1, 2, 3, 4]
after sampling, original: [1, 2, 3, 4], sample: [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

If you want a do-over to reproduce the same sample, then you should use gestate()/setstate() to reset the pseudo-random number generator's internal state in addition to preserving the original input:

```python
import random

my_data = [1,2,3,4]
print(f"original before sampling: {my_data}")

rng_state = random.getstate()
sampled_data = random.sample(my_data, 4)
print(f"after sampling, original: {my_data}, sample: {sampled_data}")

sampled_data = random.sample(my_data, 4)
print(f"without resetting PRNG, original: {my_data}, sample: {sampled_data}")

random.setstate(rng_state)
sampled_data = random.sample(my_data, 4)
print(f"after resetting PRNG, original: {my_data}, sample: {sampled_data}")
```

produces, for example:

```text
original before sampling: [1, 2, 3, 4]
after sampling, original: [1, 2, 3, 4], sample: [2, 1, 3, 4]
without resetting PRNG, original: [1, 2, 3, 4], sample: [3, 4, 1, 2]
after resetting PRNG, original: [1, 2, 3, 4], sample: [2, 1, 3, 4]
```